# What is the logic behind "Brother Backlit Sky" in the book Understanding Exposure?

Tags: technique, exposure, metering, bryan-peterson

I don't know if this question is too specific, but after reading [Understanding Exposure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0817439390), I can't understand very well the reasons and logic behind *Brother Backlit Sky* and their brothers. Although I did see that the pictures result more naturally pleasing.

I don't know if I can explain here what the book says as it's inside a paid book, but it has something to do with the metering system trying to convert everything to 18% gray.

**Update**

> From the book, you use Brother Backlit
>   Sky when shooting backlit sunrise or
>   sunset landscapes. Take a meter
>   reading to the side of the sun and use
>   it to make your image.

Comment: You can't copy whole sections from a book, but _ideas_ can't be copyrighted, so you can certainly explain the concept. You can also quote reasonable (small!) amounts from a copyrighted work under [fair use](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/fair-use-rule-copyright-material-30100.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why meter off sky, then change aperture and shutter speed?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/16031/why-meter-off-sky-then-change-aperture-and-shutter-speed)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the 'Brothers' in Understanding Exposure are an attempt to give you a simple, normally consistent thing that you can meter off that shouldn't be *too* far to the extreme.  Metering off the sky, plant foliage, and other reflectively moderate items give you a solid baseline.

The idea is that here is an object that relative to the normal scene should be a bit..in the middle so to speak.  He's not asking you to meter off something pure black or pure white because then it would throw the scene out of whack.

In reality, its a bit of a novelty to learn until you *really 'understand exposure'* in which case you should be picking your metering based on your **own judgement** of whats important to you in the scene.

Comment: Thanks. I guess to really understand exposure one needs to attend courses and LOTS of practice. (as in everything).

Comment: @Luciano - Mainly practice.